# Why do we use ovens

Tags: oven

Prompted by a question a friend asked me, I began wondering - why do we use ovens to cook food, instead of say simply relying on a hob, or a barbecue? By the way, I'm not suggesting that this would be a good idea, I do a lot of cooking in the oven, but from a theoretical viewpoint, I'm interested to know: what are the advantages that an oven has over other ways of heating food. What kind of dishes can best/only be made with an oven?

Comment: Have you done any research into how ovens work and how they heat things?

Comment: @Catija Sure, so you have the heating element which usually heats from below, and obviously an oven is a kind of chamber so the heat all gets reflected down onto the food. I understand that, but I couldn't explain to my friend, you know, why that's such a good thing. So I came here. I mean, you could just use a pot on a hob couldn't you? Or could you? I dunno, that's why I'm asking. Obviously you can't cook a whole joint of chicken in a pot on the stove, it wouldn't fit, but you know that's the kind of thing I was hoping to hear about

Comment: @Catija I'm kind of new to seasoned advice so I didn't know how much detail to put in, but I didn't think it would be good form to put a confused half-answer in the question. Originally I had a lot of background about how my friend doesn't have an oven at home and explaining the motivation for the question, but I thought it would be better to cut the biographical details and just ask my question :)

Comment: Push a button to turn of/off cooking heat source that is precisely calibrated vs. making a fire that takes time to warm up and then stays hot after it's needed and can't be fine-tuned the way an oven setting can?

Comment: A BBQ could be considered an oven.

Comment: Good luck baking a cake without an oven.

Comment: @Nameless Exactly! So this is what prompted me to ask the question, maybe I could have asked it better, I just wanted to get to the point. I was asked why we all have ovens in our homes and baking cakes was one of the things I thought about, but I couldn't tell you *why* an oven is needed for a cake and so I was hoping to get answers that would explain more about how ovens cook than the very basic understanding I currently have and why that works for certain things, because I don't really understand cooking.

Comment: If i'm told to put something in the oven i put it in the oven, but i don't know much about what goes on in there!

Comment: Do you actually know how an oven or baking works?

Comment: @Nameless Not well enough to explain to somebody who doesn't know why an oven would be useful. I understand about heat causing chemical reactions. I understand about activating yeast and their activity releasing carbon dioxide gas causing bubbles and cakes and bread to rise, I understand things in brief, and I wasn't asking for a chemistry lesson necessarily. Just, why is an oven a good thing, what does it do really well? It's like, what's special about a wok? I don't know, but there must be something that makes it such a good tool for stir-frys and stuff, the shape, the material.

Comment: Why is a wok better than a generic frying pan? There must be a reason, I think it would be quite interesting. That's the flavour of my question, what do ovens have that say a pot doesn't.

Comment: You don't see there being any difference between 600-1000 F concentrated all on the bottom of the pan and 350-450 F from all directions? Pots have to be stirred or be boiling to move the extreme heat around... ovens do not require this because the heat is coming from everywhere... I think you're getting the reaction you are because it seems so obviously different to us. So, maybe it's our problem because we know when to use one or the other... but it's not about chemistry at all. You can't cook a 20 pound turkey over direct heat without burning it.

Comment: @Catija Don't worry about it I'm not offended, but if you'd be able to synthesise something like that into an answer I think it could be quite interesting. It may not be revelatory, but I think it's well to understand why we do things, rather than just blindly doing them. So for me, for example, I cook sichuan/szechuan chicken thighs by frying then in a frying pan and I recently cooked jerk chicken thighs by baking them in the oven. To me, the chicken thigh component of the flavour tasted and looked the same. of course, the rest of the flavours were different

Comment: So I know I could cook a chicken thigh by frying it in a little oil in a frying pan, or by baking it in an oven and I doubt I would know the difference at the end of it, so I confess I wouldn't know when to use one over the other, or what the one is better for than the other. Obviously I do know that you don't bake a potato in a frying pan, but I thought rather than hand waving to my friend, the experts here might be able to offer something really interesting about what niches the oven occupies and what they do that makes them useful in those cases

Comment: Pretty sure ovens are older than pots, pans, stoves... comes from the tradition of burying food to cook more slowly and evenly than fire-roasting, progressed to heating earthen ovens (heat-sinks) with longer, slower heat for less fuel.  Tradition is a powerful force, no reason not to continue to use, and even improve, them when methods of cooking with them are already tested and tried.  And slower, even heat helps large or dense things cook through without burning, for much less effort - you can pretty much leave stuff alone in an oven, not wise on a fire or a stovetop.

Comment: In Germany, we colloquially tend to call almost all multi-hob stoves an "Ofen" (oven), whether an oven is included or not - single-hob devices (which would be simply called a "Platte", hobplate) excluded, no one will misunderstand you if you say "stell's auf'n Ofen!". Probably hailing from times were hobplates were commonly heated by an actual oven below.

Answer (score 6):

As you observe in your comment above, an oven directs heat at food from all directions, rather than just from the bottom. Some chemical reactions can occur only once you've reached a certain temperature, most notably browning reactions. You wouldn't be able to produce a crisp chicken skin or a crusty loaf of bread on the stovetop.

You can try to fake it with a "Dutch oven", which uses a thick pot to try to distribute heat from a stovetop to the sides. But it tends to trap humidity near the food, which can make things soggy, and still can't get the sides warm enough. (Dutch ovens were originally used in fire, where you could heap coals on the sides and top. You can't do that on a stovetop.)

Modern ovens have thermostats, something a stovetop lacks. That makes them very good for long, slow cooking, such as braising. You can do it on the stovetop, but with less control. Some ovens even have timers that will automatically start cooking at a specific time, and shut off based on time or temperature. That control also makes ovens good for keeping batches of pancakes warm, so that you can serve them all at once.

Finally, most ovens have broilers, which expose food directly to the heat from the top. You can't do that on a stovetop, since the heat on the bottom is diffused by a pan. A barbecue grill can produce a similar sear on meats, but broilers are necessary put a quick browning on meringue-topped pies.

Comment: "That makes them very good for long, slow cooking, such as braising. " Sadly, something people have forgotten about and are underusing.

Comment: Indeed, I have little need for a crock pot because of that. I just made stock by stewing beef bones at ~180F for three days. (After browning the bones in the oven at 500.)

Answer (score 3):

Adjunct to the good answer above: An oven, especially a still oven, also has very little rapid heat transfer capacity. Which can be a good thing - things that resist heating, due to energy being used up to evaporate moisture or cause other phase changes or endothermic reactions, will not be FORCED to heat up to temperature - compare something held still in a 500°F oven for ten minutes (probably crisp) vs anything held still on a 500°F pan for ten minutes (probably on fire)...

At the same time, the same slow heat transfer also means that the food cannot seriously COOL the cooking medium (air) - a temperature gradient will cause convection (not forced convection, as you have in a convection oven!) and thus air movement that will replace cool air with hot air...